# interface with iterate array loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, interface, implementation

I am getting problems with these 2 lines. I need to create a class with an array of Animals using constants to size it. I have to fill the array Animal with Fish and Iterate in 2 different ways through the array **executing move()** and **makeSound()**.

These are the lines:

1 `animals[0] = new Fish()`

2 `for (Animal animal : animals) {`

```
public class Animals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE = 6;
        Animal animal[] = new Animal[SIZE];
        animals[0] = new Fish()                // 1

        for (Animal animal : animals) {        // 2
            System.out.println("Bubbles");
            System.out.println("Swim");
        }
    }
}
```

My interface `Animal`:

```
public interface Animal {
        public void move();
        public void makeSound();
}
```

And my class `Fish` that implements `Animal`

```
public class Fish implements Animal{
@Override
    public void move() {
    System.out.println("Swim");
}

@Override
public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("Bubbles");
}

private String color;
public String getColor(){
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color){
    this.color = color;
    //Prefix this.color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another homework question. Get a +1 for an attempt. But what is the problem? Perhaps spelling it out will enable one to figure out the solution

Comment: Please explain exactly what's going on. You're missing a semi-colon after `new Fish()`, that could be causing issues.

Comment: I don't understand why I keep getting an error message in my ide as "animal" already defined being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of syntax errors to fix:

- Add a semicolon to the end of `animals[0] = new Fish();`
- Change `Animal animal[] = new Animal[SIZE];` to `Animal[] animals = new Animal[SIZE];`

Also, you should really be doing this in the `for` loop:

```
for(Animal animal : animals){
    animal.makeSound();
    animal.move();
   }
```

Just hard-coding print statements defeats the purpose of having the `Animal` interface, even if `Fish` is the only class implementing `Animal` at the moment.

Comment: How do you define animal and animals I tried too like this        **Animal animal[] = new Animal[SIZE];**
............ **animals[0] = new Fish();** . But when I go into the loop the ide tells me that they are already defined in the user scope. That's the only thing I don't understand I am new to this kind of a looping system.

Comment: It needs to be `Animal[] animals = new Animal[SIZE];`, not `Animal animal[] = new Animal[SIZE];`. If you're still getting an error message of any kind, please copy and paste the exact error message here (otherwise it's difficult to help solve the problem).

Comment: Your a genius lol one simple problem can you break down what the for loop in this situation is actually doing? `for (Animal animal : animals)`, Is it just comparing Animal to animals and importing the interface animal for the code inside the loop?

Comment: It's saying, "for each `Animal` inside array `animals`, call the animal's `makeSound()` function, followed by its `move()` function. So think about how that actually executes with your code, which has just one `Fish` object inside `animals`. Where is it going to go to find the fish's `makeSound()` and `move()` functions? That's pretty clear :) I highly recommend that you create another `class Elephant implements Animal`, place an `Elephant` inside `animals` along with the fish, and see what happens. Btw, thanks for accepting my answer!